# Why is there a TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this:

```
def p3(x):
        primes = [2]
        for a in range(3, x, 2):
            sqrt = a ** 0.5
            for b in range(3, sqrt, 2):
                if a % b == 0:
                    break
            if a % b != 0:
                primes.append(a)
        return primes
    print(p3(19))
```

return this:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, line 5
```

What does it mean and how do I correct it?
Thanks in advance,
LewisC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `sqrt` is a float and `range` expects strictly integers.

You probably want this:

```
for b in range(3, int(sqrt) + 1, 2):
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `int(sqrt)` will round the square root down, and the stop of `range()` is not included.  You need `int(sqrt)+1` here.  Otherwise, 9 would be considered as a prime number.

Answer (score 0):

`sqrt` is of type `float` and therefore can't be used with `range()`:

```
>>> range(1, 2.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

To fix, convert it to integer:

```
sqrt = int(a ** 0.5)
```